# How to remove limits on Disk Drive space?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, ssd

Migrated from [Hardware Reccomendations SE](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/13628/how-to-upgrade-laptop-for-2tb-ssd-when-manufacturer-supports-only-512gb?noredirect=1#comment22684_13628)

I am looking to upgrade my ASUS ROG GL703GE to have more disk space and memory, and have run into a few constraints laid out by the manufacturer. According to the [specification site](https://www.asus.com/us/Laptops/ROG-Strix-GL703/specifications/), the computer supports up to 2TB SATA for an HDD and up to 512GB SATA for SSD. If I'm upgrading my computer, I might as well go all-in, so I'd like to use a 2TB SATA SSD.

I'm assuming that, for whatever solutions exist for the disk, a similar solution can be used to upgrade memory. If not, I'll ask a separate question for that.

What can I do to remove the limit on the disk size for my device? I'm on Windows 10 x64, so there's no problems with the size of the disk itself, just the conversion from HDD to SSD.

Comment: There are no limits on hard drive or ssd size, that is just what they offered in that PC, put in what ever size you want.

Comment: @Moab tsk tsk, comments are not for answering questions. ;)